# Autocomplete - how to use jQuery function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, function, jquery-autocomplete

How can I get the value of the item selected in an autocomplete list? I have tried something like this:

```
    <script>
    $('#my_autocomplete_field').bind('railsAutocomplete.select', function(event, data){
      /* Do something here */
      alert(data.item.id);
    });
</script>

<%= f.autocomplete_field :user_id, autocomplete_user_phone_invoices_path, :update_elements => {:id => '#invoices_user_id'}, :class => 'text', :id => 'my_autocomplete_field' %>
```

I used this gem: [link to GitHub](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete)

But when I select something from the autocomplete list, nothing happens:  there is no alert message. I would like to ask is how I should to update the jQuery function to get the alert message.

I spend entire afternoon yesterday trying to solve this problem, but unfortunately I still can't find the right solution. Many thanks for every help!

Comment: In the first line of your post, do you mean to say 'how can I get the value of the item selected in an autocomplete list'?

Comment: my problem is, that in the autocomplete list are item as "NAME SURNAME", and I need to get the ID of this selected element. And when I select the item from autocomplete list, so I want to display through alert the ID of selected item.

Comment: I think this is a purely JavaScript/jQuery issue. Forget the Rails part for now and add all relevant JavaScript and HTML in your page to your question. That will help in diagnosing the problem that you are facing. It's difficult to see what's wrong with what you have provided.